# Error native-base en expo react native

Tags: react-native, expo

Tengo un problema con expo react native y native base. tengo días de buscar información en la web pero la que hayo no me sirve a mi, el error me aparece cuando ejectuo yarn web.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: sería bueno copiar el texto en lugar de añadir imágenes. También, proveer código para poder intentar reproducir el problema

Answer (score 0):

Creo que este es el mismo problema: https://forums.expo.io/t/expo-start-web-failed-to-compile-after-import-native-base/40826/9

Puedes probar estos pasos:

1. ejecutar `expo install @expo/webpack-config`
2. crea el archivo "webpack.config.js" en el nivel 'root', agrega el código a continuación:

webpack.config.js:

```
const createExpoWebpackConfigAsync = require('@expo/webpack-config');

module.exports = async function (env, argv) {
    const config = await createExpoWebpackConfigAsync({
        ...env,
        babel: {
            dangerouslyAddModulePathsToTranspile: ['@codler/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view']
        }
    }, argv);
    return config;
};
```

u otra opción:

Cambias el NPM paquete react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view.
Vas a la nativa base/dist/src/basic y abre Content.js
Cambias esto: `var _reactNativeKeyboardAwareScrollView=require('@codler/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view')` por esto: `var _reactNativeKeyboardAwareScrollView=require('react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view')`